# InvoiceAdd: This feature is not enabled or not available in this version of QuickBooks

Tags: xml, quickbooks

I am trying to add an invoice using InvoiceAdd. We are running Enterprise Solutions: Retail 13.0. When I post the following request I get the error "This feature is not enabled or not available in this version of QuickBooks."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>  
<QBXML>  
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">  
    <InvoiceAddRq>  
      <InvoiceAdd>  
        <CustomerRef>  
          <ListID>8000005A-1513350705</ListID>  
        </CustomerRef>  
        <TxnDate>2013-08-09</TxnDate>  
        <RefNumber>1003</RefNumber>  
        <BillAddress>  
          <Addr1>123 Blah Road</Addr1>  
          <Addr2>address2</Addr2>  
          <City>Somewhere</City>  
          <State>WV</State>  
          <PostalCode>55555</PostalCode>  
          <Country>US</Country>  
          <Note>  
          </Note>  
        </BillAddress>  
        <ShipAddress>  
          <Addr1>123 Blah Road</Addr1>  
          <Addr2>address2</Addr2>  
          <City>Somewhere</City>  
          <State>WV</State>  
          <PostalCode>55555</PostalCode>  
          <Country>US</Country>  
          <Note>  
          </Note>  
        </ShipAddress>  
        <DueDate>2013-08-09</DueDate>  
        <FOB>  
        </FOB>  
        <ShipMethodRef>  
          <FullName>US Mail</FullName>  
        </ShipMethodRef>  
        <Memo>  
        </Memo>  
        <Other>123065</Other>  
        <InvoiceLineAdd>  
          <ItemRef>  
            <FullName>11200</FullName>  
          </ItemRef>  
          <Desc>11200</Desc>  
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>  
          <UnitOfMeasure>ea</UnitOfMeasure>  
          <Rate>10.00000</Rate>  
        </InvoiceLineAdd>  
      </InvoiceAdd>  
    </InvoiceAddRq>  
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
```

The item exists as well as the customer and a sales order corresponding to the sales order. Let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have Units of Measure enabled, and is that a valid unit of measure for the item 11200?